# Register Sign In with fiebase is not working

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image]

Althought my code has no errors whenever I fill all the champs (FullName, email,..) and click the Register Button the data doesn't get uploaded to the database and keeps saying "Failed to register! Try again!"
Somoene told me that i have to provide my firebase uri inside the getInstance() method in order for it to work but i didn't know if that was the case.

here is my java code RegisterUser.java :

```
public class RegisterUser extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private EditText editTextFullName, editTextAge, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button registerUser;
 



    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        registerUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        registerUser.setOnClickListener(this);


        editTextFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullNameRegister);
        editTextAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageRegister);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailRegister);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordRegister);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.registerBtn:
                registerUser();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String fullName = editTextFullName.getText().toString().trim();
        String age = editTextAge.getText().toString().trim();


        if (fullName.isEmpty()){
            editTextFullName.setError("Full name is required");
            editTextFullName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (age.isEmpty()){
            editTextAge.setError("Age is required");
            editTextAge.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (email.isEmpty()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Please provide valide email!");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()){
            editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6){
            editTextPassword.setError("Min password length should be a 6 characters!");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }



        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(fullName, age, email);


                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User has been registred successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    } else {

                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register! Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register! Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

also Here is the Logcat when i click the Register Button :

```
2022-05-17 16:21:03.096 27883-27883/com.example.universityapp I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@f02b838
2022-05-17 16:21:03.097 27883-27925/com.example.universityapp W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2022-05-17 16:21:03.098 27883-27925/com.example.universityapp W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: com.example.universityapp requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
2022-05-17 16:21:03.098 27883-27925/com.example.universityapp W/GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeg is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
2022-05-17 16:21:03.117 27883-27883/com.example.universityapp D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10299; state: ENABLED
```

Comment: Have you changed rules of firebase? - https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules and implementations https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb yeah this are my rules for the Realtime Database  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb and i also already have those implementations

Comment: If you are running this on an emulator, make sure you choose a device image that includes the Google Play Store. Firebase will not function without it.

Comment: @DanHarms no I'm actually running this on my phone if you can help me find the problem I would be so thankful

Comment: Double check that you have enabled email/password authentication in your Firebase console.

Comment: @DanHarms already done that :(

Comment: Your device has Play Store and Play services installed? If so, I am not sure what else you are missing. The log indicates it can't find it.

Comment: @DanHarms yes bro, both are installed it's so strange I checked everything but I can't find the problem

Comment: Have you tried to see what's the error message when the task is not successful?